# Angular Js - Cannot read property 'push' of undefined - Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

im making a simple app, that can add a name and a description in a table.
But im getting the error of - Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

Could some one help me ?

this is my code.

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <!-- angular templating -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
    <div ng-view>          
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute','dx']);

scotchApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });

$routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/new', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/edit.html',
        controller: 'newController'
    });
})

scotchApp.controller('newController', function ($scope, $location) {

$scope.person = { name: "", description: "" };

$scope.save = function () {
    $scope.crew.push($scope.person);
    $location.path("/")
}

});

scotchApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
$scope.crew = [
    { name: "Hugo", description: "Programador" },
    { name: "Vitor Lopes", description: "Técnico de Informática" },
    { name: "Pedro Sousa", description: "Webdesigner" },
]   
});
```

HTML - new.html ( page where i have my table)

```
 <table class="table table-striped" style="width: 350px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Nome</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Descrição</strong></td>
                <td><a href="/new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="person in crew">
                <td>{{person.name}}</td>
                <td>{{person.description}}</td>
                <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

HTML - new.html ( page where i will add my new contact)

```
<form>
<input ng-model="person.name" placeholder="Enter Name"/><br />
<input ng-model="person.description" placeholder="Enter Description" /><br />
<button ng-click="save()" class="btn-primary">Save</button>
```

Thank You !!

Comment: you can't mix controllers like that?

Comment: i dont understand, sorry !

Comment: The $scope variable in newController and mainController are ISOLATED scope variables.

Comment: Take a look at the many ways to share data across controllers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers

Comment: ok...and what do i do ?

Answer (score 2):

define your array before push something like so :

```
$scope.crew = []
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, i guess my problem i because im pushing in an array that is in another controler